# how to judge android rawQuery update successfully?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("update "
            + DbMetaData.CART_TABLE_NAME + " set " + DbMetaData.PRODUCT_NUM
            + "=" + DbMetaData.PRODUCT_NUM + "+" + num + " where "
            + DbMetaData.ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
```

cursor.getCount() always return 0; so how to judge i update successfully?

Comment: can you post the whole function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rawQuery` is **preferably** used to perform `SELECT` operations. It won't let you know the number of rows changed.

You should use `sqliteDatabase.update` to perform update operations and get count of rows affected.

Comment: i found rawQuery must execute cursor.xxxx(). if not call any cursor method after rawQuery, rawQuery will have no effect

Comment: Yes, rawQuery returns Cursor, and cursors are used to read data returned from a query, and practically data rows are only returned when you do SELECT operation. So, in short, rawQuery is suitable for SELECT operations  :)